# Can I call template function pointer (predicates) in c++?

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, predicate

Consider the following example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class foo
{
public:
    std::string name;
};

template <class T>
class handle
{
    T *p;

public:
    handle(T *t) : p(t) {}
    handle() {}
    const T &operator[](size_t i) const
    {
        return p[i];
    }
    T *operator->() const
    {
        if (p)
            return p;
        else
            return 0;
    }
};

template <class T>
bool compare(const handle<T> &x, const handle<T> &y)
{
    return x->name < y->name;
}

int main()
{
    vector<handle<foo>> vec({new foo(), new foo()});
    vec[0]->name = "efg";
    vec[1]->name = "abc";
    sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), compare); //how to use template function pointer (unresolved becuase of template)
    for (auto i : vec)
    {
        cout << i->name << endl;
    }
}
```

Now what I am trying to do is to provide function pointer (predicate) for `std::sort` algorithm, but that predicate is made from template. But by the time of compilation, the type should be resolved, and the compiler should be able to match the range of `handle<foo>` againts `handle<T>`, where it is obvious the type of template is `foo`. So why am I getting error:

```
no matching function for call to ‘sort(std::vector<handle<foo> >::iterator, std::vector<handle<foo> >::iterator, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
```

where "unresolved overloaded function type" should be resolved by time of compilation (the time when template params are resolved, so should template function).

Comment: `compare` is not a function. It is a template for a function. `compare<foo>` is a function.

Comment: Compile fine [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4789e7bf75ed9b39).